# Two Fragments where only one has a Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have two `Fragments`, where A has a `toolbar` and B doesn't. In B's onCreateView I call this method:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideToolbar();
```

Which is basically:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

And when I switch from B to A I call:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
    .hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("B"))
    .commit();
// Opposite of hiding toolbar method
((MainActivity) getActivity()).showToolbar();
```

It then shows the toolbar, the problem is that the toolbar shows before the `FragmentTransaction` is done. If I wait till the transaction is done to show the toolbar, it will also look stupid as the entire fragment is visible before the toolbar is shown. Is there a way to show one Fragment above another where the one that is shown on top doesn't have a toolbar and the one below keeps its toolbar when it is hidden?

Answer (score 1):

In the fragment that you want to hide the toolbar , add this code

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
 }


@Override
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
  ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
 }
```